# Unable to upgrade to Scala 2.13.6

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to migrate to Scala - 2.13.6 and Akka - 2.6.16 with akka-actor_2.13 version 2.6.16.

Code

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpCharsets.UTF-8
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.MediaTypes.{application/json, application/xml}

object MyPayloadType extends Enumeration {

val XML,
JSON = Value

def getMyPayloadType(contentType: Value): ContentType.NonBinary = contentType match {

case XML => ContentType(`application/xml`, `UTF-8`)

case JSON => ContentType(`application/json`)
}
}
```

Above code gives the following compilation error.

> Symbol 'type Scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized' is missing from the classpath.
>
> This symbol is required by 'class akka.util.ByteString'

Comment: May you share your `build.sbt` or `pom.xml` file? Aren't you importing by mistake or transitively Scala 2.11 or 2.12?

Comment: also asked at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/error-upgrading-to-scala-2-13-6/7842/3

Comment: Thanks! Have moved all the dependencies to Scala 2.12 which resolved the issue.